# Implement semaphore in User Level C

Tags: c, operating-system, semaphore, atomic, locks

An effective and necessary implementation of semaphore requires it to be atomic instruction.

I see several User level C implementations on the internet implementing semaphores using variables like count or a data structure like queue. But, the instructions involving variable donot run as atomic instructions. So how can anyone implement a sempahore in User Level C.

How does a c library semaphore.h implement semaphore?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is almost certainly "it doesn't" - instead it will call into kernel services which provide the necessary atomic operations.

Comment: Not necessarily, although this would be the simplest solution for resources shared across processes with distinct address spaces. Implementing synchronization primitives in user space would still benefit performance-wise.

Comment: It would only benefit peformace if the average thread wait time is less than the time saved by avoiding the syscall; user-space code cannot remove execution from waiting threads.

Comment: @MartinJames sure, this is only feasible for user level threads, I should have added this. With "normal" kernel level threads, you could think about really needing a semaphore and maybe use some lock-free implementation (again using atomics) instead, but that's not the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in *standard* C until [c11](/questions/tagged/c11). What you need is, as you said, *atomic* operations. [c11](/questions/tagged/c11) finally specifies them, see for example [stdatomic.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).

If you're on an older version of the standard, you have to either use embedded assembler directly or rely on vendor-specific extensions of your compiler, see for example the [GCC atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html). Of course, processors support instructions for memory barriers, *check and swap* operations etc. They're just not accessible from pure [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) and earlier because parallel execution wasn't in the scope of the standard.

After reading MartinJames' comment, I should add clarification here: This only applies if you implement all your threading in user space because a semaphore must block threads waiting on it, so if the threads are managed by the kernel's scheduler (as is the case with pthreads on Linux for example), it's necessary to do a syscall. Not in the scope of your question, but atomic operations might *still* be interesting for implementing e.g. lock-free datastructures.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement semaphore operations as simple as:

```
void sema_post(atomic_uint *value) {
    unsigned old = 0;
    while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(value, &old, old + 1));
}

void sema_wait(atomic_uint *value) {
    unsigned old = 1;
    while (old == 0 || !atomic_compare_exchange_weak(value, &old, old - 1));
}
```

It's OK semantically, but it does busy waiting (spinning) in `sema_wait`. (Note that `sema_post` is lock-free, although it also may spin.) Instead it should sleep until `value` becomes positive. This problem cannot be solved with atomics because all atomic operations are non-blocking. Here you need help from OS kernel. So an efficient semaphore could use similar algorithm based on atomics but go into kernel in two cases (see Linux *futex* for more details on this approach):

- `sema_wait`: when it finds `value == 0`, ask to sleep
- `sema_post`: when it has incremented `value` from 0 to 1, ask to wake another sleeping thread if any

In general, to implement a lock-free (using atomics) operations on a data structure it's required that every operation is applicable to any state. For semaphores, *wait* isn't applicable to value 0.